# Numpy array pass-by-value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, move-semantics

I have a numpy array that is changed by a function. 
After calling the function I want to proceed with the initial value of the array (value before calling the modifying function)

```
# Init of the array
array = np.array([1, 2, 3])

# Function that modifies array
func(array)

# Print the init value [1,2,3]
print(array)
```

Is there a way to pass the array by value or am I obligated to make a deep copy?

Comment: Save a copy before going into `func` and use that later on?

Comment: Yes, you are. Numpy arrays are mutable objects, so any change made to it is reflected across all variables pointing to that object. If you don't want that, make a `.copy()`.

Comment: Python does not support multiple evaluation strategies. You *must* make a copy if you want to work on a copy. You *shouldn't* need a *deep copy*, unless you have a `numpy` array of `object` type...

Comment: you don't need `deepcopy()` from `copy` module but np.array method `zzz.copy()` where zzz is an ndarray

Comment: Calling it `array` doesn't make it an array...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I mentioned, `np.ndarray` objects are mutable data structures. This means that any variables that refer to a particular object will all reflect changes when a change is made to the object.

However, keep in mind that *most* numpy functions that transform arrays return new array objects, leaving the original unchanged.

What you need to do in this scenario depends on exactly what you're doing. If your function modifies the same array in place, then you'll need to pass a copy to the function. You can do this with [`np.ndarray.copy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html).

Comment: Worked for me. Trying to improve the answer, use-


`new_array =  np.ndarray.copy(array_needs_to_be_copied)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following library (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynverse) that inverts your function and call it, like so :

```
from pynverse import inversefunc

cube = (lambda x: x**3)
invcube = inversefunc(cube)

arr = func(arr)

In [0]: arr
Out[0]: array([1, 8, 27], dtype=int32)

In [1]: invcube(arr)
Out[1]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: "Unfortunately, there are no easy ways to keep in memory arr if you call arr = func(arr)." Sure there is. `arr2 = arr; arr = func(arr)`

Comment: Also, "If you don't assign your new array modified by func to array, then print(array) will still show you the initial value" is not true in *general*. Consider the function `def func(a): a[0] = 42`

Comment: What if you have `def func(arr): arr *= 2`?

Comment: You guys are right, edited my answer to remove these mistakes !